# How to get social media icons to open in a new tab or window in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, tabs, icons

In working on multiple sites, I find that you can either turn on or off social media icons, but that they all default to opening in the same window.  Does anyone know how to make them open in another tab or window?  If so, how/where do I make these changes.

In one instance, I'm using the ShareThis plugin, in another I'm using the Colorway WordPress theme.  I've googled and googled and can't seem to get an answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

There will either be an option for "open link in a new window" (usually a checkbox) in the widget screen or the plugin settings.

If there's NOT - unfortunately, have to use jQuery Something like `$('a.social').attr('target', '_blank');` or in the php (plugins > editor, or appearance > editor) - and you'll have to find the code that says something like `<a href="<?php get_option('facebook', 'share-this'); ?>"></a>` and at `target="_blank"` to it.